# Societal effects of succubi invasion?

Tags: society, magic, mythical-creatures, sex

A year from now an ancient cult opens a portal to another reality with the hope that demons invade the earth, but instead they summon 2 billion playful succubi. They are harmless when in a good mood, but can wreak havoc when angry and they want to engage in sexual activities with all human males (they need to do it in order to survive). How would society evolve in 10 years from now?

Misc. notes:

- The succubi look like women but have long elven ears, bat-like or bird-like wings and horns.
- They can have any kind of eye, horn and hair colour; they also have perfect facial features/bodies.
- They can reproduce with human males and their genitals feel 500% better than those of a normal human female; also, their skin produces a very strong pheromone that makes men feel dizzy and aroused.
- Succubi are hard to kill.
- Magic: They have powerful elemental magic and limited teleportation, as well as healing abilities. The magic can be inherited to their offspring if they reproduce with human males.
- The succubi can't enter holy ground.

Comment: Do they drain the life force from their partners like a traditional succubus?  What kind of offspring do they have; half-breeds, full-breeds with some minor trait variance?  Can they have male offspring, and if so were do they fall under the previous question?  Now that magic is proven real, can more people learn it?

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile Half-breeds can only be male and are able to learn magic,Full breeds are true succubus and always female.Normal people can learn magic if they consume the heart of a succubi or half-breed.Yes the succubi can drain the life but only when starving of energy or angry.

Comment: What do you mean by _starving_? Starving wrt food or starving wrt sex?

Comment: What level of magic do humans on your alternate earth possess? Opening a portal to another reality probably isn't particularly basic stuff so there must be some degree of specialism going on in humans even if it isn't widely known.

Comment: @LioElbammalf The level of magic attainable by human wizzards is enough to open wormholes or burn a small town with fingertips,But in order to achieve that the wizzards need to train for a long time and eat the souls of humans or animals,Larger animal/human is better.

Comment: This question is terribly worded, too broad, and poorly thought out. ***their genitalia is 500% better than a normal human female*** <- what the heck is that supposed to mean? Is the OP 12 or something? Maybe what was meant is that sex is more enjoyable, but sex is not merely enjoyable because the "genitalia is over 9000". There's a strong psychological component to it. There's also no explanation as to any side effects of the mating, such as losing life "energy" or whatever. ***skin produces a very strong pheromone*** <- which does what, exactly? Sheesh

Comment: @AndreiROM Yes i mean that,Be aware that i dont speak english at 100%. Whoa 3 humans already offended,WTF.

Comment: @alexdarkshine - not speaking English 100% is fine. But you seem not to have thought out this question very well. Consider, for a second, the economic consequences of 2 billion more "people" suddenly coming into existence. "People" who's only interest is to breed, because that's essentially the entire purpose of their existence. You're looking first at massive housing shortages, and social and economic breakdown. In the medium to long term, however, you're probably looking at mass starvation, and war. You have not put _any_ effort into thinking this through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Politics (in addition to other answers):

Usually, when people suddenly spawn in your country, you have to put them somewhere (at least until you can kick them out or decide to keep them). In this case, the first thing your average political leader will try to do is to send them all back home. Once it has been realized that it can't be done (because magic), then the fun will start.

So let's assume that all succubi escaped from many portal scattered around the world, you'll have 27% more human-like creatures on earth. To scale it down to a country, It means 86.1 million illegal immigrants in the US you'd have to <strike>throw over a wall</strike> house and feed.

Any average, normally, constituted political leader would freak out without a doubt and send the military after you succubus horde because they are demons, and it is somewhat accepted in the western culture that demons have to die (because of Christian roots). No matter how tough they are, a lot will indeed die in the first few months, probably a lot of humans too.

I'm not telling that it might end up in a war, I'm telling that it cannot NOT end up in a war, 2 billion is too much, there is no good political answer to this number of 2 legged sentient things, you can't house them, you can't feed them, heck you can barely stash them.

So since I know it's probably not the story you want to tell, here are two suggestions:

1. Reduce their number to less than 300 million (around 4% of world population). it's still a heck of a lot but it's bellow the bar of "oh shit we gotta do all we can now" and even if a witch hunt will start, it'll not be an open war between demons and mankind, because there are not enough enemies.
2. Instead of making them pop-out out of thin air, turn 2 billion female humans into succubi (maybe through permanent possession). In this case open war in unlikely because it'll be very easy for succubi to hide behind their host's former identity and very hard to go on an open war against them. There'll still probably be some form of witch hunt performed by the authority just like in the previous scenario.

In a witch hunt scenario, you'll get a lot more interactions between succubi and humans that you would in an open war scenario. In this case, everything suggested in other answers apply and you can put the witch hunt in the background of your story far more easily that you can with an open war

Comment: @AlexDarkshine You should also probably reduce the scope of your question to make it more suitable for wb.se. Question starring "how society would react" are put on hold most of the time, explain what you are the most interested in, economics, habits, demography, customs, church, family ...  And also, don't taunt those who put the question on hold, it's unlikely to be reopened if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Alex, in a lot of myths, Succubi drain the life force from their "victims."

If that's not the case, and it looks like that's not the way you are going, then a lot of guys in college are going to be really happy.  However, from your comment, it looks like Succubi will be hunted, possibly to extinction, since eating their heart can give a person the ability to wield magic.

Prostitution would be almost non-existent.  Why pay if you know you can get it for free?

On the whole, aside from hunting for magic giving hearts, in ten years, there will probably be more changes from gaining the ability to use magic than from the introduction of the succubi.

Comment: How do you think women will react? Would they hate the succubi out by jealously?

Comment: Many, yes.  Many, no.  The big question is:  are the succubi interested in having a relationship or just an energy boost?  If the latter, some women will be pragmatic about it.  It's your story, how do you want them to react?

Comment: @AlexDarkshine Depends, are the succubi willing to share? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The societal effects are extremely vast and can potentially rollback all human technological development.

**1- Sex slavery**

A lot of sexually hyperactive males will happily become sex slaves of these powerful demons. Considering that these enchantresses also know magic and can benefit (financially or physically) their slaves, the trend will probably increase rapidly until it peaks out at a point where there would be several men willing to join the harem of a succubus.

**2- Crumbling of family systems**

The availability of new (and apparently more appealing) sex partners will have a highly negative effect on the sexual status of human women with human men. This will create extreme problems in the current family structure as men and women (in general, exceptions would definitely exist) would no longer be bonded as strongly as previously.

**4- Indirect effects of family structure breakdown**

Teen delinquency, drug abuse, suicide rates and incidents of violence will increase. Initially the human society will break into isms, schisms, groups and affiliations, will would at least take decades, if not centuries to reunite into a coherent social system again.

**5- Long term human population reduction**

Considering the enchanting effects of these demons and their penchant for copulating with human males, human women would get lesser attention from human men. This would have devastating long term (within 10 years or so) effect on the population of humans in low (human) population countries where birth rate is already less. Europe would specially be hard hit. Gradually the population of half-breeds and then true-bloods will rise as human population dwindles.

Comment: You seem to overlook the fact that the legal foundation of marriage is actually property law. Who inherits, and/or owns what. The societal interpretation of sexual fidelity might change to include one night stands with these demons (for both men _and_ women), but that doesn't necessarily mean that people would stop getting married and forming families. After all, you sleep with the demon once or twice, but you have children, and raise them with your spouse. Increased teen delinquency and crime is also not a natural consequence of freely available sex. Frankly, your answer seems half-baked.

Comment: Maybe it sounds half-baked to you. As long as OP is satisfied with my description, personal opinions from other community members matter little. I would have tried and replied you if it was an objective scientific question and scientific laws/theories were involved @AndreiROM